# Warning [function.include]: failed to open stream WP-Login

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I believe similar questions have been asked but none of the fixes seems to match my scenario. Maybe I am doing it totally wrong but I keep getting this error on my login page.

```
 Warning: include(/home/thebrooklynstar/Maildir/cur/cache/load.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/thebrooklynstar/.bash(5) : eval()'d code on line 1

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/home/thebrooklynstar/Maildir/cur/cache/load.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php5/lib/pear') in /home/thebrooklynstar/.bash(5) : eval()'d code on line 1

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/thebrooklynstar/.bash(5) : eval()'d code:1) in /home/thebrooklynstar/thebrooklynstar.com/wp-login.php on line 290

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/thebrooklynstar/.bash(5) : eval()'d code:1) in /home/thebrooklynstar/thebrooklynstar.com/wp-login.php on line 302

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/thebrooklynstar/.bash(5) : eval()'d code:1) in /home/thebrooklynstar/thebrooklynstar.com/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 662

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/thebrooklynstar/.bash(5) : eval()'d code:1) in /home/thebrooklynstar/thebrooklynstar.com/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 663

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/thebrooklynstar/.bash(5) : eval()'d code:1) in /home/thebrooklynstar/thebrooklynstar.com/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 664

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/thebrooklynstar/.bash(5) : eval()'d code:1) in /home/thebrooklynstar/thebrooklynstar.com/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 865
```

Here is also what the wp-login.php file looks like from 290-304:

```
header('Content-Type: '.get_bloginfo('html_type').'; charset='.get_bloginfo('charset'));

if ( defined('RELOCATE') ) { // Move flag is set
    if ( isset( $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ) && ($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] != $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) )
        $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = str_replace( $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );

    $schema = ( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) == 'on' ) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
    if ( dirname($schema . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) != get_option('siteurl') )
        update_option('siteurl', dirname($schema . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) );
}

//Set a cookie now to see if they are supported by the browser.
setcookie(TEST_COOKIE, 'WP Cookie check', 0, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
if ( SITECOOKIEPATH != COOKIEPATH )
    setcookie(TEST_COOKIE, 'WP Cookie check', 0, SITECOOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Figure out why `/home/thebrooklynstar/Maildir/cur/cache/load.php` is missing.

Comment: @doge hey man im a total newbie. Would you have any suggestions as to why it could be missing? ? Should I try to clear my cache?

Comment: Possible, I'm not familiar with the software you're using. The `cache` folder is a good indication it might be used for cache files.

Comment: @doge I was going to do this 1. Remove entire wp-cache directory from wp-content.
2. Open wp-config.php and add below line to permanently disable cache .

define('DISABLE_CACHE', true);